# TypeError: $(...).get(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I am a kind of newbie to the canvas. I am trying to hard code a html page to display different diagrams. For this I am having a html page like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

 <script>
 $.getScript(path + "js/display.js");
 </script>

 <div data-role="header">  

 </div>  
 <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px" onload="loadSQLRecords();">

      <input type="button" data-inline="true" class="appButton" value="Display Chart" id="LoadReservatButton" onclick="currentPage.displaychart();" /> 

 </div>
```

and the login.js like:

```
currentPage={};

currentPage.init = function() {
WL.Logger.debug("report :: init");
};

currentPage.displaychart=function(){
WL.Logger.debug("payment :: loadGenReportPage");
pagesHistory.push(path + "pages/chart.html");
$("#pagePort").load(path + "pages/chart.html");
loadSQLRecords();

};

function loadSQLRecords(){

var ctx = $('#myCanvas').get(0).getContext('2d');
// Box1-ESPS P1
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "1";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.rect(5, 5, 100, 100);  
ctx.stroke();
}
```

and the chart.html page is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.getScript(path + "js/display.js");
</script>


<div data-role="header">  

</div>  
<div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px" onload="loadSQLRecords();">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="750" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"/>

</div>
```

But, I am getting an error that TypeError: $(...).get(...) is undefined. Can anyone please let me know my mistake here?

Comment: `$.getScript` should be failing as written. If it isn't, then you likely have jquery included twice.

Comment: `div`s don't have an `onload` attribute. Or at least it doesn't do anything. `div`s don't load anything.

Comment: the error is before you open the canvas, because if you do make a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qzz6a7o0/1/ then it is working

Comment: Put the $.getScript part below the <script ...jquery-1.8.3.min.js/> link.

Comment: Sorry all, I could not find a solution though following your suggestions. I have changed my code, please find it, and let me know my mistake..

Comment: It means that `$('#myCanvas')` did not select the element you expected to be there.

Comment: yeah... @Bergi, but seriously dont know what to do. It is a bummer where I have been strucked..

Comment: @Srujana: The dupe I've linked explores a few probable cases and solutions to the problem.